# Is it safe to use special characters in java code?

Tags: java

My language is Portuguese, so i need to write a method `doSomething()`, which in Portuguese is `façaAlgo()`.
Java allows me to use special characters in the code, but is it safe? What are the disadvantages of doing so? Or can i use it without worrying?

Comment: It should be fine if it compiles and runs. There shouldn't be any performance loss either, since variable names don't matter after compiling.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's valid Java, but you're slightly more likely to run into problems when:

- Transferring your source code between computers
- Compiling
- Editing

Pretty much everything handles ASCII with no problems, and most encodings are either compatible with ASCII or editors will guess correctly if you use ASCII. However, when you start using characters outside ASCII, you need to make sure everything uses the same encoding, or you'll end up with different tools thinking your code has different characters in.

If you *do* use non-ASCII characters, I'd recommend using UTF-8 as the encoding - it's supported basically everywhere these days. Make sure whatever IDE you're using creates new files using UTF-8 by default, and expects existing files to be in UTF-8. Then if you compile from the command line, use the `-encoding` command line argument to specify the encoding.

Comment: If I may add, it will be rapidly a nightmare. Got enough problem with the UI encoding vs files (wrong encoding, some libraries doesn't support it, etc). I would suggest to use only non-ascii for UI, and keeping the code without it. Using facaAlgo() instead of façaAlgo() will probably not have a big impact on the lisibility of your code.

Comment: Wouldn't this problem also happen with String constants? Like a message to the user: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Faça algo!");`
In this case we can't always avoid using non-ascii characters on the code.

Comment: @MateusViccari you could avoid non-ASCII by using a Unicode escape: `"Fa\u00e7a algo!"` but that would ofcourse be unreadable for a human...

Comment: @Mateus: Often you'd put user-visible text into properties files,  for i18n purposes. But yes, if you put the strings in source you have the same *potential* issues.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer to your question: yes. See [the Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html):

> Variable names are case-sensitive. A variable's name can be any legal
>      identifier — an unlimited-length sequence of Unicode letters and
>      digits, beginning with a letter, the dollar sign "$", or the
>      underscore character "*". The convention, however, is to always begin
>      your variable names with a letter, not "$" or "*". Additionally, the
>      dollar sign character, by convention, is never used at all. You may
>      find some situations where auto-generated names will contain the
>      dollar sign, but your variable names should always avoid using it. A
>      similar convention exists for the underscore character; while it's
>      technically legal to begin your variable's name with "_", this
>      practice is discouraged. White space is not permitted.

Answer (score 1):

Java has support for unicode in source files.  If you end up having issues in the future, it's possible to specify the encoding when compiling.